# Laravel 8 + PHP 8: using optional route optional parameter give "Cannot use positional argument after named argument"

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, php-8

Using Laravel 8 with PHP 8, and trying to set up optional parameters in routing:

```
Route::prefix('manual')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{type}/{topic?}/{subtopic?}', 'PageController@manual')
        ->name('manual');
})
```

controller (tried both false and null):

```
public function manual($type, $topic = false, $subtopic = false) {
```

gives the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Cannot use positional argument after named argument
```

when I call this route URL like /manual/manualName or /manual/manualName/a/b
How can I solve it?